# Parsing xml file in Python 3 with minidom

Tags: xml, python-3.x, minidom

I have a xml file contains some information about clients. I need to parse (I'm not a programmer) it and I use xml.dom\minidom and Python 3

## My file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <Root timestamp="1552777261" formatver="1.0">
            <ClientInfo>
                <Client Name="Bob" Surname="Smith" Age="15.09.1898" FirstVisit="15.09.2018" LastVisit="15.09.2024">
                    <Type Hight="5.6" Weight="200" />
                    <Job Profession="Developer" Salary="3000" City="Chicago" />
                    <Family Wife="True" Son="True" Daughter="False" />
                    <FamilyInfo>
                        <Names NameWife="Sarah" NameSon="John" NameDaughter="Sony" NameCat="Catty" NameDog="Doggy" />
                    </FamilyInfo>
                <Passions Sport="soccer" Activity="Traveling" Social="Blood donor" />
                </Client>
                <!-- (...)  -->
            </ClientInfo>
        </Root>
```

## My code:

```
        (...)
        f = minidom.parse(path_to_xml_file)
        itemlist = f.getElementsByTagName('Client')
        print(len(itemlist))

        for s in itemlist:
            print("     ",s.attributes['Name'].value)
            print("     ",s.attributes['Age'].value)
            print("     ",s.attributes['Date'].value)
            print("     ",s.attributes['FirstVisit'].value)
            print("     ",s.attributes['LastVisit'].value)
        (...)
```

## My output:

```
    Bob
        Smith
        15.09.1898
        FirstVisit
        LastVisit
```

My question - how to parse the file to get the following output? I do not understand how to get access to tags , ,  etc

```
    Bob
        Smith
        15.09.1898
        FirstVisit
        LastVisit
            5.6
            200
            Developer
            3000
            Chicago
            True
            True
            False
                Sarah
                John
                Sony
                Catty
                Doggy
    soccer
    Traveling
    Blood donor
```

Thanks